# For each value in a column, check if it belongs to any interval in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, intervals

Let's say I have a list of positions values :

```r
> head(jap["POS"])
      POS
1  836924
2  922009
3 1036959
4 141607615
5 164000000 
6 118528028 
[...]
```

And a list of intervals :

```r
> genes_of_interest
       MGAM        SI      TREH    SLC2A2  SLC2A5   SLC5A1  TAS1R3       LCT
1 141607613 164696686 118528026 170714137 9095166 32439248 1266660 136545420
2 141806547 164796284 118550359 170744539 9148537 32509016 1270694 136594754
```

I want to check for every position in the first dataframe, if it is inside any of the intervals in the second dataframe.

So in this case, I should have

```r
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Since `141607615` belongs to first interval (`MGAM`) and `118528028` belongs to 3rd interval (`TREH`).

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to go through all columns in `genes_of_interest` and compare the position shown in `jap` with the intervals. Then wrap it with another `apply` to determine if `any` of the rows is `TRUE`. Or we can replace the outer `apply` with `as.logical(rowSums())`, the outputs for both functions are the same.

Note the `between` function comes from the `dplyr` package.

```r
library(dplyr)

apply(sapply(1:ncol(genes_of_interest), \(x) between(jap$POS, genes_of_interest[1, x], genes_of_interest[2, x])), 1, any)

# or 

as.logical(rowSums(sapply(1:ncol(genes_of_interest), \(x) between(jap$POS, genes_of_interest[1, x], genes_of_interest[2, x]))))
```

#### Output

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr 1.1.0 and up you can use a non-equi `left_join()` if you first turn `genes_of_interest` into a tidy format. This will be very fast and should be very flexible if you have other columns to also join by.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

jap <- tibble(
  POS = c(836924, 922009, 1036959, 141607615, 164000000, 118528028)
)

genes_of_interest <- tribble(
  ~MGAM, ~SI, ~TREH, ~SLC2A2, ~SLC2A5, ~SLC5A1, ~TAS1R3, ~LCT,
  141607613, 164696686, 118528026, 170714137, 9095166, 32439248, 1266660, 136545420,
  141806547, 164796284, 118550359, 170744539, 9148537, 32509016, 1270694, 136594754
)

# Manipulate `genes_of_interest` into a tidy data format
genes_of_interest <- genes_of_interest %>%
  mutate(bound = c("start", "end")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-bound) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = bound, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(match = TRUE)

genes_of_interest 
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   name       start       end match
#>   <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 MGAM   141607613 141806547 TRUE 
#> 2 SI     164696686 164796284 TRUE 
#> 3 TREH   118528026 118550359 TRUE 
#> 4 SLC2A2 170714137 170744539 TRUE 
#> 5 SLC2A5   9095166   9148537 TRUE 
#> 6 SLC5A1  32439248  32509016 TRUE 
#> 7 TAS1R3   1266660   1270694 TRUE 
#> 8 LCT    136545420 136594754 TRUE

jap %>%
  left_join(
    genes_of_interest,
    by = join_by(between(POS, start, end)),
    multiple = "any"
  ) %>%
  mutate(match = !is.na(match))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>         POS name      start       end match
#>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1    836924 <NA>         NA        NA FALSE
#> 2    922009 <NA>         NA        NA FALSE
#> 3   1036959 <NA>         NA        NA FALSE
#> 4 141607615 MGAM  141607613 141806547 TRUE 
#> 5 164000000 <NA>         NA        NA FALSE
#> 6 118528028 TREH  118528026 118550359 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

using matrices:

```
a <- matrix(jap$POS, nrow(df), ncol(df2))
b <- t(genes_of_interest)
low <- matrix(b[,1], nrow(df), ncol(df2), byrow = TRUE)
up <- matrix(b[,2], nrow(df), ncol(df2), byrow = TRUE)
rowSums(a > low & a < up)>0
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```